# Check for all combinations of key values in array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, intersect

I have this dataset to work with:

```
Array
(
    [John Doe] => Array
        (
            [137] => 7
            [22] => 8
            [145] => 7
        )

    [George] => Array
        (
            [143] => 2
            [18] => 7
        )

    [Alisa Baumbach] => Array
        (
            [148] => 7
            [145] => 5
        )

)
```

Now I want to see if I have atleast one match between the user arrays between on their keys. I would do this by using array_intersect_key:

```
$matches = array_intersect_key($user_cor['John Doe'], $user_cor['Alisa Baumbach']);
```

This works ofcourse but these values are hardcoded, I want to automate this to run all combinations through it. How would I go about checking if:

- User 1 data intersects with User 2
- User 2 data intersects with User 3
- User 1 data intersects with User 3

Ofcourse this is already minified to 3 comparisons instead of 6 since I removed the doubles because I only want unique combinations. How would I go about doing this?

I know this seems fairly typical and all but I have a lot of difficulty with phrasing this let alone searching for answers on how to do this.

Your time would be greatly appreciated in helping me understand this problem.

Comment: this is a simple `foreach($myArray as $user => $userArrays)` X 2

Comment: True but I obviously want to input more data.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
$keys = array_keys($user_cor);
for ($i = 0;$i < count($keys);$i++) {
    for ($j = $i+1;$j < count($keys);$j++) {
        $matches[$i.",".$j] = array_intersect_key($user_cor[$keys[$i]], $user_cor[$keys[$j]])
    }
}
```